# get array from R.array

Tags: android

i want to get array from myapp.R.array.***.
means if i have this array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name ="processName">
        <item >solve</item>
        <item >simplify</item>
        <item >plot</item>
        <item ></item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

then i must have in variable : `["solve","simplify","plot","",]`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html. 
`String[] name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.processName)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking from @Raghunandan's comment, you can use the getStringArray() method.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
String[] processNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.processName);
```

You can then traverse the array as normal, or put it into an adapter if you are trying to display the options in a spinner or list view.

Be sure to note that you need a context in order to use this method. So, if you are not inside of an Activity, you'll need to use a passed reference to a context.

```
String[] processNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.processName);
```